# What happens when there are two functions with the same signature in the same namespace?

Tags: c++, xcode, namespaces

As far as I understand, I can use namespaces to avoid functions overriding each other. But what if the namespaces have the same names?

I included both of the .h files below, called VideoLibrary::check() and it compiles. Why? Doesn't it contradict the purpose of namespace?

file1.h and file2.h:

```
namespace VideoLibrary
{
  void check();
}
```

file1.cpp:

```
namespace VideoLibrary
{
  void check()
    {
        printf("check1");
    }
}
```

file2.cpp:

```
namespace VideoLibrary
{
  void check()
    {
        printf("check2");
    }
}
```

I'm concerned mostly because my project includes external libraries, and i'm worrying it includes functions with the same signature as in my project. How can I get any error for such a case in compilation time?
I'm using Xcode as an editor if it matters.

Comment: "How can I get any error for such a case in compilation time?" if those functions are in separate translation units there is no way

Comment: "What happens when there are two functions with the same signature in the same namespace?" : Trouble. Usually compiler error or linker error depending on the code structure.

Comment: @JesperJuhl if that function defined in a library most probably there would not be any error

Comment: Can you fix your `file1.cpp` or your question will be answered formal way - currently you have 2 separate functions in different namespaces

Comment: @Slava, I thought we were talking about two same name functions in different namespaces, in this case, I can't really tell what function will be called.

Comment: @anastaciu unfortunately OP does not care about his question, I am pretty sure he/she is missing line in `file1.cpp` because then question and extra brackets would make sense

Comment: Hi, @Slava i've edited now, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 (non inline) definitions of the same function in different translation unit, you have an ODR (One definition rule) violation NDR (No diagnostic require).